# Initialising object with variable type

Tags: java, class

I have one `Worker` interface with one method:

```
interface Worker {
    public void work()
}
```

I have 2 classes that implements `Worker`,

```
class RoadWorker implements Worker {
    public void setPropertyA() {}
    public void work() {}
}
```

another one,

```
class GardenWorker implements Worker {
    public void setPropertyB() {}
    public void work() {}
}
```

In my `Application` class - based on some input flag - I want to instantiate one specific type of worker...

```
class Application {
    // flag
    String whichWorker = "Road";

    // instantiate
    if (whichWorker == "Road") {
        RoadWorker worker = new RoadWorker();
        worker.setPropertyA();
    } else {
        GardenWorker worker = new GardenWorker();
        worker.setPropertyB();
    }

    // use
    worker.work();  <----- OF COURSE THIS DOES NOT WORK (no reference)
```

So, I tried this -

```
class Application {
    // flag
    String whichWorker = "Road";
    Worker worker;

    // instantiate
    if (whichWorker == "Road") {
        worker = new RoadWorker();
        worker.setPropertyA(); <----- DOES NOT WORK 
    } else {
        worker = new GardenWorker();
        worker.setPropertyB(); <----- DOES NOT WORK 
    }

    // use
    worker.work();
```

My question is - how do I design my program to achieve this requirement? I know one crude option is to define worker as `Object` but then I will have to do lots of lots of type casting that I don't want. Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: **Do not use == to compare strings!!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use constructors to set properties or a factory pattern.

The first solution is simpler but has its limits:

```
interface Worker {
    public void work()
}

class RoadWorker implements Worker {
  RoadWorker(PropertyA property) {
   this.property = property;
  }
}

void foo() {
  Worker worker = null;

  if (whichWorker.equals("road")) {
    worker = new RoadWorker(property);
  }

  worker.work();
}
```

Two side notes:

- don't compare things with ==, use equals instead
- use an Enum instead that a string to switch over the worker type, they exist right for this purpose

If you nee more flexibility then a [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) could be more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

```
Worker anyworker = null;
if ("Road".equals( whichWorker )) {
    RoadWorker worker = new RoadWorker();
    worker.setPropertyA();
    anyworker = worker;
} else {
    GardenWorker worker = new GardenWorker();
    worker.setPropertyB();
    anyworker = worker;
}
```

Or pass the specific property values in the subclass constructor.

Comment: Thanks. That looks simple to me. Would you know what is the dis/advantage of this approach over passing values through constructor approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the constructors for the worker implementations do the actions specific to those implementations.

RoadWorker:

```
class RoadWorker implements Worker {
    public RoadWorker() {
        this.setPropertyA();
    }

    public void setPropertyA() {}
    public void work() {}
}
```

GardenWorker:

```
class GardenWorker implements Worker {
    public GardenWorker() {
        this.setPropertyB();
    }

    public void setPropertyB() {}
    public void work() {}
}
```

Then remove those calls to the `setProperty` methods in your if statement:

```
class Application {
    // flag
    String whichWorker = "Road";
    Worker worker;

    // instantiate
    if (whichWorker.equals("Road")) {
        worker = new RoadWorker();
    } else {
        worker = new GardenWorker();
    }

    // use
    worker.work();
```

Note: I changed `whichWorker == "Road"` to `whichWorker.equals("Road")`, because for String comparison, you need to use `equals` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your worker instance with its proper instanciation type when you set its property.

For instance

```
if (whichWorker == "Road") {
    worker = new RoadWorker();
    ((RoadWorker)worker).setPropertyA();  
} else {
    worker = new GardenWorker();
    ((GardenWorker)worker).setPropertyB();
}
```

This should work